# There exists a constact $\lambda$ s.t. $f=\lambda g$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question**

> Let $f,g$ be entire functions such that $|f(z)| \leq |g(z)|$ for all $z\in \Bbb{C}$. Then there exists a $\lambda \in \Bbb{C}$ such that $f=\lambda g$.

**My attempt**

The function $\frac{f}{g}$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb{C}\setminus g^{-1}(0)$. We may assume that the zeros of $g$ are isolated (if not, then $g$ would identically vanish and the claim is obvious). Since $|\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}|\leq 1$ for all $z\in \Bbb{C}\setminus g^{-1}(0)$, the function $\frac{f}{g}$ is bounded near each singularity, hence each singularity is removable. So really, $\frac{f}{g}$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb{C}$. Then since it's also bounded, Liouville's theorem implies that it is constant, so $\frac{f}{g} = \lambda$ for some $\lambda \in \Bbb{C}$.

Is this correct? In particular I'm not sure if my argument for removing the singularities of $\frac{f}{g}$ is correct.

Comment: Yes, you're argument is correct. Good job.

Comment: I would add that $f$ is zero, if $g$ is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would phrase your argument slightly differently. I'm not saying your phrasing is *wrong*, it's just a little less clear than it could be.

I would say that since $h(z) = \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is a bounded function, there must exist (for each point at which $a$ it is not defined) a function $H_a$ which is equal to $h$ everywhere where $h$ is defined, but is also defined on $a$.

Then, you can construct a function $H$ which is defined on $\mathbb C$ and is equal to $h$ on the domain of $h$. You can then show that $H$ is constnt, meaning that $h$ is constant on its domain.

Still, that only proves that $f(z) = \lambda g(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb C\setminus g^{-1}(0)$. You still need one more argument (which is simple) to prove equality over all $\mathbb C$