# Prove that a function is a constant multiple of the other

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f$ and $g$ be entire functions and:
$$|(f(z)| \leq |g(z)|$$
can you show me how to prove that
$$f(z)=cg(z)$$
, where c is a (complex) constant? I have been able to prove this for the case $g(z) \neq 0$ by dividing $f$ into $g$:
$$
\frac{|f|}{|g|} \leq 1 \rightarrow f(z)=cg(z) \text{by Liouville's theorem}
$$
However, I don't know how to prove this result for the more general case in which $g(z)$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Another one (for entire functions) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313298/there-exists-a-constact-lambda-s-t-f-lambda-g.

Answer (score 0):

The zeros of $g$ must be discrete, if not, $g=0$ and hence the result follows. We conclude that $f/g$ has only removable singularities, an entire function $h$ coincides with $f/g$ except for removable singularities, and $h$ is bounded, so $h=c$, and the result follows.

Comment: Could you show me how to prove it?

Comment: Actually you can look at the "duplicate" link.

Comment: I did. The link talked about meromorphic functions, and I just started learning complex analysis and have only learned about entire functions so far. Also, the link assumes without proving for the case $f$ and $g$ being entire.

Comment: Find a ball such that $g$ has no zero inside, then $f=cg$ on this ball. And we know that if entire function that coincide with a connected open set must coincide throughout.

Comment: @TheOblivious: Entire functions are just meromorphic functions in $\Bbb C$ without poles, so the same proof can be used here, with $P_f$ being an empty set.

Comment: @user284331: The essential point (that $f/g$ has only removable singularities and therefore can be extended to an entire function) is missing in your answer. There is no Liouville theorem for functions holomorphic in a ball.

Comment: Ah... yes, you are right, thanks for reminding.

Comment: I looked at the second link, too. Could you explain to me what it means by saying that the singularities are "removable"? Is there a theorem related to that statement?

Comment: @TheOblivious: The first Google hit for "removable singularity" is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity, with Riemann's theorem ...

Answer (score 0):

If you know some basic facts about order of zeros of an analytic function (and the fact that if f is analytic at all points except a and if f is bounded near a then it is actually analytic in a neighborhood of a) you can argue as follows: we first show that if g has a zero of order n at a point a then f has a zero of order m at a with $m \geq n$. Indeed, $g(a)=0$ implies $f(a)=0$; let m be the order of zero of f at a. Then we can write $f(z)= (z-a)^{m}f_1 (z)$ and $g(z)= (z-a)^{m}g_1 (z)$ in a disc around a where $f_1,g_1$ are analytic in the disc and do not vanish at a. If $m<n$ divide the inequality $|(z-a)^{m}f_1 (z)| \leq |(z-a)^{n}g_1 (z)|$ by $(z-a)^{m}$ and let $z \to a$ to get a contradiction. Thus $m \geq n$. From this it follows $\frac f g$ can be defined in an obvious way at a whenver $g(a)=0$. This makes $\frac f g$ a bounded entire function, hence a constant by Liouville's Theorem.

Comment: Could you explain to me how we get a contradiction as $z \to a$? Thank you.

Comment: @ A Slow Learner If you let $z \to a$ in $|f_1(z)| \leq |z-a|^{m-n} |g_1(z)|$ you get $f_1 (a)=0$ but $f_1$ does not vanis at $a$.

Comment: In your comment above, didn't you mean $|z-a|^{n-m}$?

Comment: @A Slow Learner, Yes, sorry I typed $m-n$ for $n-m$.